# Existence of root of nondegenerate operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A: C^n \to C^n$ has zero kernel. How one can prove that there is operator $B$ such that $A = B^k$? (I don't know if k is limited somehow or not)

Comment: Well, in a rather boring way, $\;A=A^1\;$ ...I think you're going to be more specific in *what you really* want.

Comment: I think he wants to show that this is possible for any $k>0$ and $C$ is the field of complex numbers.

Comment: There is  nothing told about $k$ in problem, but it clearly should be $k > 0$

Answer (score 4):

Consider the case where you have an operator $T \colon \mathbb{C}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^k$ of the form $T = \lambda I + N$ where $\lambda \neq 0$ and $N$ is nilpotent. Motivated by the Taylor series for $(1+x)^{\alpha}$, you can define

$$ B = \lambda^{\frac{1}{k}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} { \frac{1}{k} \choose n} \left( \frac{N}{\lambda} \right)^{n} $$

where $\lambda^{\frac{1}{k}}$ is any complex $k$-root of $\lambda$. The operator $B$ is well-defined as $N$ is nilpotent and you can verify that $B^k = T$.

The general case follows by Jordan decomposition as every invertible operator $A \colon \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^n$ is conjugate to a direct sum of operators of the form above.